# Crash on initialisation of microphone on iPhone Pro Max 14

Tags: ios, iphone, crash, audiokit, avaudioengine

I am seeing a new crash in Testflight on iPhone 14 Pro Max (iOS 16.1) devices, it seems to happen consistently and repeatedly on the anonymous user's device, although I haven't been able to get a physical iPhone 14 Pro Max to reproduce (the app works in the simulator on Pro Max 14). The app uses AudioKit 4.11.2 for mic tracking, as well as a sequencer with a polyphonic synth. The crash seems to happen on the initialisation of the microphone (with AKMicrophone).

I wonder if there is any difference in the sample rate or input / output format on the new devices which causes the crash? What would be the best way to handle this?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

The microphone is initialised here with the microphone stored as a class variable as advised for audiokit. The initialisation of AKMicrophone() fails consistently

```
private var mic: AKMicrophone?

private func setupMicInput() {
        
        mic = AKMicrophone() ** CRASH **
        
        guard let mic = mic else { return }

        if !mic.isStarted {
            mic.start()
        }
                
        let audioInputs = AKManager.inputDevices!.compactMap { $0 }
        
        // this is the bottom microphone
        do {
            try mic.setDevice(audioInputs[0])
        } catch {
            Log(error, category: .audio)
        }
    }
```

Please see crash report here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yalEO.png

0   CoreFoundation                  0x1bbc1de88 __exceptionPreprocess + 164 (NSException.m:202)
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1b4f4b8d8 objc_exception_throw + 60 (objc-exception.mm:356)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x1bbd8a814 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 96 (NSException.m:0)
3   AVFAudio                        0x1d25a14a4 AVAE_RaiseException(NSString*, ...) + 52 (AVAEInternal.h:69)
4   AVFAudio                        0x1d2672cfc AVAudioIONodeImpl::SetOutputFormat(unsigned long, AVAudioFormat*) + 864 (AVAEInternal.h:77)
5   AVFAudio                        0x1d25ed97c AVAudioEngineGraph::_Connect(AVAudioNodeImplBase*, AVAudioNodeImplBase*, unsigned int, unsigned int, AVAudioFormat*) + 5088 (AVAudioEngineGraph.mm:2308)
6   AVFAudio                        0x1d268d510 AVAudioEngineImpl::Connect(AVAudioNode*, AVAudioNode*, unsigned long, unsigned long, AVAudioFormat*) + 1488 (AVAudioEngineGraph.mm:2122)
7   AVFAudio                        0x1d2690d00 -[AVAudioEngine connect:to:format:] + 128 (AVAudioEngine.mm:836)
8                               0x102c7db1c specialized AKMicrophone.init(with:) + 1024 (AKMicrophone.swift:50)
9                               0x102c7cccc AKMicrophone.init(with:) + 20 (:0)
10                              0x102305ac4 AKMicrophone.__allocating_init(with:) + 24 (:0)
11     0x102305ac4 AudioManager.setupMicInput() + 60 (AudioManager.swift:325)